# How can I simplify tensor product expressions quickly?

Tags: measurement, terminology-and-notation, bell-basis

Suppose I have a 2-qubit system in the first Bell state, $\left| \beta_{00} \right>$. I want to make the measurement in the computational/$Z$-basis on the first qubit, say qubit $A$. That means I am calculating the quantity $\left< \beta_{00} \right| \big(  \left| 0_A \right> \left< 0_A \right| ⊗ 1_B \big) \left| \beta_{00} \right>$.

Ignoring the $\frac{1}{2}$ that comes up, how do I quickly calculate the quantity $\big( \left<00 \right|+\left< 11 \right|\big)\left| 0_A \right> \left< 0_A \right|$? I am ignoring the second part of the equation because I am stuck on calculating this quantity itself. In the notes I have, the $\left< 11 \right|$ is also struck out to be 0 without any explanation.

Is there a way to do these kinds of calculations quickly?

Comment: Since $\langle 1|0\rangle=0$, the $\langle 11|$ term is struck out. Knowing which states are orthogonal is a quick way to simplify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach it in two ways:

1. Try simplifying in the Dirac notation.

(which is the quickest, but there is some learning curve to it. You will need to work through some questions to develop the ability to solve using this method quickly.)

2. Write everything out in matrix/vector representation and do the calculations.

(This is easy and straightforward but is tedious and generally slow, but it works well for 1 and 2-qubit cases.)

---

**Method 2:**

We know, in the computational basis,

$$|\beta_{00} \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}\,.$$

Also,

$$\langle \beta_{00} | = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}1 &0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}\,.$$

Now, let's compute

$$
\begin{align}
|0\rangle_A \langle0| \otimes I_B &= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 &1 \end{bmatrix}\,,\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 &0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 &1 \end{bmatrix}\,,\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}\,.
\end{align}
$$

So now, you can calculate
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \beta_{00} | \bigg(|0\rangle_A \langle0| \otimes I_B \bigg)| \beta_{00} \rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}1 &0&0&1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}
\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}\,, \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\,.
\end{align}
$$

---

**Method 1:**

We have
$$|\beta_{00} \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big( |0\rangle_A |0\rangle_B + |1\rangle_A |1\rangle_B\big)\,.$$

So, let's calculate

$$
\begin{align}
\langle \beta_{00} | \big(|0\rangle_A \langle0| \otimes I_B \big)| \beta_{00} \rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( \langle 0|_A  \langle 0|_B +  \langle 1 |_A \langle 1|_B \big)\cdot(|0\rangle_A \langle0| \otimes I_B \big)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( |0\rangle_A |0\rangle_B + |1\rangle_A |1\rangle_B\big)\,,\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\bigg( \underbrace{\langle 0|0\rangle_A}_{1} \langle 0|_A \langle 0|_B I_B + \underbrace{\langle 1|0\rangle_A}_{0} \langle 0|_A \langle 0|_B I_B        \bigg) \cdot \big( |0\rangle_A |0\rangle_B + |1\rangle_A |1\rangle_B\big)\,,\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \langle 0|_A  \langle 0|_B  \bigg) \cdot  \big( |0\rangle_A |0\rangle_B + |1\rangle_A |1\rangle_B\big)\,,\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \big( \underbrace{\langle 0|0\rangle_A}_{1} \cdot \underbrace{\langle 0  |0\rangle_B}_{1}   + \underbrace{\langle 0|1\rangle_A}_{0} \cdot \underbrace{\langle 0 |1\rangle_B}_{0}    \big)\,, \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\,.
\end{align}
$$